# How to send messages to a temporal channel created in another handler?

Tags: java, multithreading, spring-integration

Maybe there is some "integration-pattern" here I miss...

I have a proccess (a thread from an TaskExecutor) that is some cases need to stop and wait for an additional data to continue.

I was thinking about blocking in a receive method, but I don't find how to send, from a different thread a message to that channel (a temporal one, isn't it?) to unblock this thread, only this.

The component responsible about unblock should receive a message from some kind of messagin platform (redis,rabbit,...) and then "notify" the blocked execution.

An ugly implementation could be a wait/notify but of course I don't want to use that having a full "message-oriented" solution.

Is there any component/solution for this problem? 
Maybe a subscriber with some topic I can use to be sure only that thead ir running again, but I cannot block in a publishsubscribe channel, can I?

thanks a lot,

Answer (score 1):

> that is some cases need to stop and wait for an additional data to continue.

Looks like this is indeed the use-case for the [Thread Barrier](https://docs.spring.io/spring-integration/docs/5.0.0.RELEASE/reference/html/messaging-routing-chapter.html#barrier) component.

Another way to do something similar is an [Aggregator](https://docs.spring.io/spring-integration/docs/5.0.0.RELEASE/reference/html/messaging-routing-chapter.html#aggregator) for the `releaseStrategy` as 2 messages by size.

Anyway the `correlationKey` is a key entity in both use-cases.

Comment: Although I couldn't apply this solution (just for some architectural reasons in our side, and lack of proper Spring Integration version at this moment) I was checking docs and improving my knowledge of SI,... I will use this approach asap, thanks Artem!